# OFDM combined with chirp signal

Tags: digital-communications

I want to achieve OFDM modulation combined with a chirp signal (for example a LFM signal). Is it correct to do as below (this is a global scheme):

1. Mapping
2. Spreading with chirp signal
3. OFDM Modulation
4. Channel
5. OFDM Demodulation
6. Despreading with chirp signal
7. Demapping

Comment: Hi, can you add more details about what you're wanting to achieve? The way I read your question, the answer is (1) generate OFDM signal, (2) generate LFM signal, and (3) add them together. But I'm guessing you are after something else!